# Select a column value of DataGridView in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am developing an application in Visual Studio 2010 c#.

I have two forms as shown in this image:

[image]

In Form2 I have a `DataGridView` control with the user's name, and in Form1 I have a TextBox and a Button. I opened Form2 by:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.ShowDialog();
```

How can I get the selected column value of GDataGridView in the Form1 TextBox?

Comment: I am sorry. I need Cell value. thanks Deffiss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a clean code that addresses your situation

Assume you have two form **Form1** and **Form2**

`Form 1` has **textbox** and **Button**. On **Button click** `Form2` is displayed

`Form1.cs`

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              Form2 f = new Form2();
              f.DataGridCell += new Action<string>(f_DatagridCell);
              f.ShowDialog();
        }

       void f_DatagridCell(string obj)
       {
         textBox1.Text = obj;
       }
```

and in your `Form2.cs`

```
      public event Action<string> DataGridCell ;


       private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
       {
        try
        {
            if (DatagridCell!=null)
            {
                var value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                DatagridCell(value);

            }

        }
        catch { }
    }
```

And you are done :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:
To get Selected Grid value

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
{
    string selectedval;
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    selectedval= row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value
}
```

Define a property of the form like, then use this in other places it would be available with the form instance

```
public string SetText
{
  get { return textBox1.Text; }
  set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ganesh I am getting below error on line row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value; that 'Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement'

Comment: try: return row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value; ... return is missing in the original post ...

Comment: @Ashok_Karale you will get selected value in 'selectedval' variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use event to solve the issue. Just create an event in your form2 like this

```
public event Action<string> DatagridCellSelected;
```

In your form1 hookup a method with this event.

```
DatagridCellSelected+=form2_DatagridCellSelected;
```

In this method do something like this

```
textbox1.Text = obj;
```

Now in your form2 handle DataGridView cell enter event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
    DatagridCellSelected(value ?? "");
}
```

Comment: May be you should to add a null-checking before publishing the event?

Comment: Ya sure. That can cause some real problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is my variant. Add this properties to your Form class with data grid:

```
    public DataGridViewCell SelectedCell
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0 ? dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0] : null;
        }
    }

    public string SelectedValue 
    {
        get
        {

            var val = SelectedCell != null ? SelectedCell.Value : null;
            return val != null ? val.ToString() : null;
        }
        set
        {
            SelectedCell.Value = value;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
form.SelectedValue = "123";
```

This will be work correctly only if selected only one cell.

Answer (score -1):

Found correct answer with all your suggestion.

Thank you for your help.

Here is my working code for all needy people.

In Form1

```
private void BtnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
            textBox1.Text= frm._textBox1.ToString();
        }
        public string _textBox
        {
            set { textBox1.Text = value; }
        }
```

and in Form2

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            string val = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = val;
            this.Close();
        }
        public string _textBox1
        {
            get { return textBox1.Text.Trim(); }
        }
```

cheers..!!!!!!!!!